# Difference between "result", "consequence", "outcome"

Tags: difference, nouns

Can you tell me the difference between *result*, *consequence*, *outcome* and the use of each words?

Comment: What did **you** figure out in your research? At what sources have you look at? What is not clear to you after consulting dictionaries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three words share a common core concept: what comes after an event or action. What is unique to each word is connotation.

**Consequence** almost always carries a suggestion of something potentially or actually negative. One would *not* expect some one to say, "as a consequence of your work ethic over the past month, you are getting a promotion!" One does not generally want to "face the consequences" as it's not likely to be a good thing.

**Result** and **outcome** are more alike, in that there is no implied negativity.

**Result** is more commonly used in regular conversation, and is most appropriate in referring to what are the effects of some actions. So "the result of your diligent study was a good grade on the test."

**Outcome** is most commonly used in technical settings, and has a more specific meaning relating to the final observed results in a study or at the end of an observational period. For instance: "placing an IV immediately upon admittance to the ER often results in shorter ER stays, but is not necessarily correlated with positive patient outcomes based upon primary provider follow-up and patient surveys."

As another example, the **result** of raising prices might be higher profit margins, but the **outcome** of a pricing strategy may be less profit from a reduced number of sales.

### Summary

When in doubt, use **result** because it implies the least. When you want to imply something *negative*, or *potentially negative*, use **consequence**. Reserve **outcome** for formal, technical discussions.

Comment: I think you're letting the connotations of *face the consequences* colour your judgement. People don't normally say "As a consequence of your work ethic over the past month, you are being fired!" either. But in contexts where it *is* likely to be used, it's as much neutral or positive as negative. One difference I *would* flag up is that *outcome* has more implications of ***finality*** (you often get *intermediate results*, but rarely *intermediate outcomes*). I think another is that *consequence* implies ***logical** connection* more strongly.